# use MediaQuery textScaleFactor with VRouter package flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**i want to use textScaleFactor in my app and to use must use in MaterialApp, and i use VRouter package, Is there a way to use it with this package?**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<void> authenticationCheck(BuildContext context,
      {VRedirector vRedirector}) async {
    if (userRepo.currentUser.value.auth != true) {
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      vRedirector.push('/login',
          queryParameters: {'redirectedFrom': '${vRedirector.to}'});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: settingRepo.setting,
        builder: (context, Setting _setting, _) {
          return VRouter(
            title: 'Ta3mer Vendor',
            locale: _setting.mobileLanguage.value,
            localizationsDelegates: [
              S.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
            theme: _setting.brightness.value == Brightness.light
                ? ThemeData(
                    fontFamily: 'proximanova-regular',
                    primaryColor: Colors.white,
                    disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                    cardColor: Colors.white,
                    secondaryHeaderColor: Color(0xFF043832).withOpacity(1.0),
                    brightness: Brightness.light,
                    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch()
                        .copyWith(secondary: Color(0xFF180968)),
                    primaryColorLight: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    dividerColor: Color(0xFF8c98a8).withOpacity(0.1),
                    focusColor: Color(0xFF8c98a8).withOpacity(1.0),
                    primaryColorDark: Color(0xFF180968),
                    textTheme: TextTheme(
                      headline5: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          color: Color(0xFF043832).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.3),
                      headline4: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Color(0xFF043832).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.3),
                      headline3: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Color(0xFF043832).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.3),
                      headline2: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Color(0xFF180968).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.4),
                      headline1: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Color(0xFF043832).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.4),
                      subtitle1: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          height: 1.3),
                      subtitle2: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: Color(0xFF043832).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.2),
                      headline6: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Color(0xFF180968).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.3),
                      bodyText2: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          height: 1.2),
                      bodyText1: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Color(0xFF043832).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.3),
                      caption: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: Color(0xFF8c98a8).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.7),
                    ),
                  )
                : ThemeData(
                    fontFamily: 'proximanova-regular',
                    brightness: Brightness.dark,
                    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF2C2C2C),
                    primaryColorLight: Colors.white,
                    primaryColor: Color(0xFF2C2C2C),
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF9999aa),
                    colorScheme: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.copyWith(
                        background: const Color(0xFF000000),
                        onBackground: const Color(0xFF2e2e2e),
                        primary: const Color(0xFF6553D9),
                        onPrimary: const Color(0xFFeeeeee),
                        brightness: Brightness.dark,
                        secondary: Color(0xFF180968)),
                    dividerColor: Color(0xFF9999aa).withOpacity(0.1),
                    hintColor: Color(0xFFccccdd).withOpacity(0.1),
                    focusColor: Color(0xFF9999aa).withOpacity(1),
                    primaryColorDark: Color(0xFF180968),
                    textTheme: TextTheme(
                      headline5: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          color: Color(0xFF9999aa).withOpacity(1),
                          height: 1.3),
                      headline4: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Color(0xFF9999aa).withOpacity(1),
                          height: 1.3),
                      headline3: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Color(0xFF9999aa).withOpacity(1),
                          height: 1.3),
                      headline2: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Color(0xFF180968).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.4),
                      headline1: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Color(0xFFffffff).withOpacity(1),
                          height: 1.4),
                      subtitle1: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Color(0xFF9999aa).withOpacity(1),
                          height: 1.3),
                      subtitle2: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: Color(0xFF9999aa).withOpacity(1),
                          height: 1.2),
                      headline6: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          color: Color(0xFF180968).withOpacity(1.0),
                          height: 1.3),
                      bodyText2: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Color(0xFF9999aa).withOpacity(1),
                          height: 1.2),
                      bodyText1: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Color(0xFF9999aa).withOpacity(1),
                          height: 1.3),
                      caption: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          color: Color(0xFF9999aa).withOpacity(0.6),
                          height: 1.2),
                    ),
                  ),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            routes: [
              VWidget(path: '/login', widget: HomePage()),
              VGuard(
                beforeEnter: (vRedirector) =>
                    authenticationCheck(context, vRedirector: vRedirector),
                stackedRoutes: [
                  VPopHandler(
                    onPop: (_) async => print('POP'),
                    stackedRoutes: [
                      VNester(
                        path: null,
                        name: 'VNester1',
                        widgetBuilder: (child) => MyScaffold(
                          child,
                          title: 'VNester1',
                        ),
                        nestedRoutes: [
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/Order',
                            name: 'Orders',
                            widget: Orders(),
                            aliases: ['/Orders'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/takeaway',
                            name: 'Orders',
                            widget: OrdersTakeaway(),
                            aliases: ['/Orders'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/pos_checkout',
                            name: 'pos_checkout',
                            widget: PosCheckout(),
                            aliases: ['/pos_checkout'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/BestSellerMemberShip',
                            name: 'BestSellerMemberShip',
                            widget: BestSellerMembership(),
                            aliases: ['/BestSellerMemberShip'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/ReturnOrder',
                            name: 'ReturnOrder',
                            widget: ReturnOrder(),
                            aliases: ['/ReturnOrder'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/wallet',
                            name: 'wallet',
                            widget: WalletWidget(),
                            aliases: ['/wallet'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/coupon',
                            name: 'coupon',
                            widget: CouponPage(),
                            aliases: ['/coupon'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/productlist',
                            name: 'productlist',
                            widget: ProductList(),
                            aliases: ['/productlist'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/itemlist',
                            name: 'itemlist',
                            widget: RTypeProductList(),
                            aliases: ['/itemlist'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/add_product',
                            name: 'add_product',
                            widget: AddProduct(),
                            aliases: ['/add_product'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/add_item',
                            name: 'add_item',
                            widget: AddItem(),
                            aliases: ['/add_item'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/deliverytimeslot',
                            name: 'deliverytimrslot',
                            widget: DeliveryTimeSlot(),
                            aliases: ['/add_product'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/vendorlist',
                            name: 'vendorlist',
                            widget: VendorList(),
                            aliases: ['/vendorlist'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/profile',
                            name: 'profile',
                            widget: ProfileView(),
                            aliases: ['/profiledata'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/subcategory',
                            name: 'subcategory',
                            widget: SubCategoryPage(),
                            aliases: ['/subcategory'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/dashboard',
                            name: 'dashboard',
                            widget: DashboardWidget(),
                            aliases: ['/dashboard'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/banner',
                            name: 'banner',
                            widget: Banners(),
                            aliases: ['/banner'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/invoice/:id',
                            name: 'invoice',
                            widget: InvoiceWidget(),
                            aliases: ['/invoice'],
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/category',
                            widget: CategoryPage(),

                            // Custom transition
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/bulk_upload',
                            widget: BulkUpload(),

                            // Custom transition
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/report',
                            widget: Report(),

                            // Custom transition
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/language',
                            widget: LanguagesWidget(),
                            // Custom transition
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/Barcode',
                            widget: BarCodePdf(),

                            // Custom transition
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/Wallet',
                            widget: WalletWidget(),

                            // Custom transition
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/Pos_Checkout',
                            widget: PosCheckout(),

                            // Custom transition
                          ),
                          VWidget(
                            path: '/thermalSlip',
                            widget: Slip(),

                            // Custom transition
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              VRouteRedirector(
                redirectTo: '/login',
                path: r':_(.*)',
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

**This is my main page, and the way it is supposed to be followed is like this**

```
 return MaterialApp(
            builder: (context, child) {
              return MediaQuery(
                child: child,
                data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 0.9),
              );
            },
```

**The application is built entirely on this package and cannot be changed, any solutions?**

Comment: please do NOT use textScaleFactor.  That is for the accessibility features of your device to communicate with your app.  When you override the value, you are making it difficult for people who need larger type.  Instead, construct a Theme that represents your selected fontsizes.  But, consider that the Material folks have researched and published the existing sizes, and spent more money than you ever have coming up with those numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After some research and experimentation, I came to this solution**

```
return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: settingRepo.setting,

        builder: (context, Setting _setting, _) {
          return VRouter(
            builder: (context, child) {
              return MediaQuery(
                child: child,
                data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 0.9),
              );
            },
```

**just use builder in VRouter**